# The general solution of the ODE $x^2y''+5xy'+13y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the ODE $$x^2y''+5xy'+13y=0$$.

Need a confirmation that answer is   $$y=\dfrac{1}{x^2}\bigg(c_1 \cos(3\ln x)+c_2 \sin(3\ln x)\bigg)$$

I do not understand what quality standards are on this website .

Comment: Your submission needs to have a certain length (not entirely sure why). You sound like you got a feedback reminding you of it; that's probably all.

Comment: i just typed the bottom question to fill in space :)

Comment: Have you tried substituting your expression for $y$ into the left hand side of the differential equation and checking that it reduces to $0$?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: so do i pick an arbitrary constant value?

Comment: @blbl: You can determine these arbitrary constants only if you are given initial values.

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal so albanese is wrong ? ( the above comment)

Comment: @blbl: He is right. He is just telling you how to check if your solution is right or wrong by substituting back in the differential equation.

Comment: @blbl : just find $y'$ and $y''$ and plug them into the left-hand side of the ODE and see if it simplifies to $0$.  That's how you _confirm_ it's a solution.  This is not the same thing as _solving_ the ODE.  From your question it is unclear which you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the auxiliary equation $$am^2+(b-a)m+c=0$$ wherein $a=1$,the coefficient of $x^2$, $b=5$,the coefficient of $x$ and $c=13$

for finding the possible $m$'s. Now, if $m_1,m_2$ are distinct solutions so the general solution of your Cauchy-Euler ODE will be as $$y_c=C_1x^{m_1}+C_2x^{m_2}$$ If you have $m_1=m_2=m=\frac{a-b}{2a}$ then $y_c=C_1x^m+C_2x^m\ln(x)$ and finally if you have $m=\alpha\pm i\beta$ then $$y_c=x^{\alpha}(C_1\cos(\beta\ln x)+C_2\sin(\beta\ln x))$$ where $C_1,C_2$  are constants. Of course $x\in(0,+\infty)$. Your solution looks fine.

Comment: Nice support and confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute any values in the "arbitrary constants" to **check** but it would certainly be not a general solution.

The general solution of a differential equation represent a family of curves , satisfying the above equation.So, by substitution you pick up any arbitrary curve from the family and check the differential equation.

Or i'll suggest just construct the DE from the equation you got. differentiate it twice and eliminate the constants from the equations you get . If the DE you get is same , then the answer is correct.

Comment: Though not to be prefered but $c_1=c_2=0$ satisfy. :p